# adding lists with different length to a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two lists with different lengths, like `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[2,3]`

I would like to generate a `pd.DataFrame` from them, by padding nan at the beginning of list, like this:

```
   a  b
1  1  nan 
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

I would appreciate a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) method:

```
from  itertools import  zip_longest
a=[1,2,3] 
b=[2,3]

L = [a, b]
iterables = (reversed(it) for it in L)
out = list(reversed(list(zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=np.nan))))

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
   a    b
0  1  NaN
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
```

Alternative, if `b` has less values like `a` list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, ([np.nan]*(len(a)-len(b)))+b)), columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
   a    b
0  1  NaN
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b.append(np.nan)#append NaN
b=list(set(b))#Use set to rearrange and then return to list
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns=['a','b'])#dataframe

Alternatively
b.append(np.nan)#append NaN
b=list(dict.fromkeys(b))#Use dict to rearrange and return then to list.This creates dict with the items in the list as keys and values as none but in an ordered manner getting NaN to the top
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns=['a','b'])#dataframe
```

[image]